# How to fix Nvidia driver's problem on Ubuntu 20.04 for old GeForce GT 240 (340)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm a happy owner of antiques GeForce GT 240.

Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have any easy way to install drivers for it (someone suggest use old kernels... horrible...). Once long ago I've done it, but completely forgot how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what should one do?
First - delete old nvidia*

```
sudo apt delete --purge nvidia*
```

Some one said that you should be careful with `nvidia-common` since it has something to do with `ubuntu-desktop`. But I saw no trace of `nvidia-common` in my Ubuntu 20.04.

At this point, do not reboot!

And now do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-340-updates nvidia-340-updates-dev xorg-modulepath-fix
sudo reboot
```

I had no problem. Hope it will not only help someone but I'll remember it myself.